# Can I know what is in my .Rdata file without opening it

Tags: r

Our group has invested a great amount of time into saving all of our work into .Rdata files. Unfortuneatly we have not invested time into creating a database.

So, each of our data experiments are saved into lists of data frames and other objects within the R class list. Our files are ~500MB to 2GB, so loading these experiments are not trivial, and I have hundreds to go through.

Is there away to get list names, dataframe names, or any other information without opening the entire .Rdata file.

Comment: The names of objects should be contained in a hex dump of the uncompressed `Rdata` file. See https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000470.shtml

Comment: @Frank Thank you, That is more information than any of the question I just followed had.

Comment: I had a similar challenge, and simply sorted it by writing a short program to cycle through a set of .RData files and create a data frame with basic contents of each, i.e. object name, class, dimensions.  I then left the computer to invest some time overnight, and picked up the content data in the morning.  If you are interested in that as an alternative approach, I would be happy to post the code.